# ElasticSearch NEST combining AND with OR queries

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

## Problem

How do you write NEST code to generate an elastic search query for this simple boolean logic?

```
term1 && (term2 || term3 || term4)
```

Pseudo code on my implementation of this logic using Nest (5.2) statement to query ElasticSearch (5.2)

```
// additional requirements
( truckOemName = "HYSTER" && truckModelName = "S40FT" && partCategoryCode = "RECO" && partID != "")

//Section I can't get working correctly
AND (
    ( SerialRangeInclusiveFrom <= "F187V-6785D" AND SerialRangeInclusiveTo >= "F187V-6060D" )
    OR 
    ( SerialRangeInclusiveFrom = "" || SerialRangeInclusiveTo = "" )
)
```

## Interpretation of Related Documentation

The *"Combining queries with || or should clauses"* in [Writing Bool Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_combining_queries_with_or_should_clauses) mentions

> The `bool` query does not quite follow the same boolean logic you expect from a programming language. `term1 && (term2 || term3 || term4)` does not become

```
bool
|___must
|   |___term1
|
|___should
   |___term2
   |___term3
   |___term4
```

> you could get back results that only contain term1

**which is exactly what I think is happening.**

But their answer to solve this is above my understanding of how to apply it with Nest.  The answer is either?

> 1. Add parentheses to force evaluation order (i am)
> 2. Use `boost` factor? (what?)

## Code

Here's the NEST code

```
 var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticPart>();
 var terms = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<ElasticPart>, QueryContainer>>
 {
     s =>
         (s.TermRange(r => r.Field(f => f.SerialRangeInclusiveFrom)
              .LessThanOrEquals(dataSearchParameters.SerialRangeEnd))
          &&
          s.TermRange(r => r.Field(f => f.SerialRangeInclusiveTo)
              .GreaterThanOrEquals(dataSearchParameters.SerialRangeStart)))
         //None of the data that matches these ORs returns with the query this code generates, below.
         ||
         (!s.Exists(exists => exists.Field(f => f.SerialRangeInclusiveFrom))
          ||
          !s.Exists(exists => exists.Field(f => f.SerialRangeInclusiveTo))
         )
 };

 //Terms is the piece in question
 searchDescriptor.Query(s => s.Bool(bq => bq.Filter(terms))
     && !s.Terms(term => term.Field(x => x.OemID)
         .Terms(RulesHelper.GetOemExclusionList(exclusions))));

 searchDescriptor.Aggregations(a => a
     .Terms(aggPartInformation, t => t.Script(s => s.Inline(script)).Size(50000))
 );
 searchDescriptor.Type(string.Empty);
 searchDescriptor.Size(0);

 var searchResponse = ElasticClient.Search<ElasticPart>(searchDescriptor);
```

Here's the ES JSON query it generates

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{ "truckOemName": { "value":"HYSTER" }}
            },
            {
               "term":{ "truckModelName": { "value":"S40FT" }}
            },
            {
               "term":{ "partCategoryCode": { "value":"RECO" }}
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "bool":{
                           "must":[
                              {
                                 "range":{ "serialRangeInclusiveFrom": { "lte":"F187V-6785D" }}
                              },
                              {
                                 "range":{ "serialRangeInclusiveTo": { "gte":"F187V-6060D" }}
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "bool":{
                           "must_not":[
                              {
                                 "exists":{ "field":"serialRangeInclusiveFrom" }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "bool":{
                           "must_not":[
                              {
                                 "exists":{ "field":"serialRangeInclusiveTo" }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "exists":{
                  "field":"partID"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the query we'd like it to generate that seems to work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": { "truckOemName": { "value": "HYSTER" }}
              },
              {
                "term": {"truckModelName": { "value": "S40FT" }}
              },
              {
                "term": {"partCategoryCode": { "value": "RECO" }}
              },
              {
                "exists": { "field": "partID" }
              }
            ],
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": { "serialRangeInclusiveFrom": {"lte": "F187V-6785D"}}
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {"serialRangeInclusiveTo": {"gte": "F187V-6060D"}}
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {"field": "serialRangeInclusiveFrom"}
                    },
                    {
                      "exists": {  "field": "serialRangeInclusiveTo"}
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Documentation

- [Combining Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)
- [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
- [Writing Bool Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_combining_queries_with_or_should_clauses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With overloaded operators for `bool` queries, it is not possible to express a `must` clause combined with a `should` clause i.e.

```
term1 && (term2 || term3 || term4)
```

becomes

```
bool
|___must
   |___term1
   |___bool
       |___should
           |___term2
           |___term3
           |___term4
```

which is a `bool` query with two `must` clauses where the second `must` clause is a `bool` query where there has to be a match for at least one of the `should` clauses. NEST combines the queries like this because it matches the expectation for boolean logic within .NET.

***If*** it did become

```
bool
|___must
|   |___term1
|
|___should
   |___term2
   |___term3
   |___term4
```

a document is considered a match if it satisfies only the `must` clause. The `should` clauses in this case act as a boost i.e. if a document matches one or more of the `should` clauses in addition to the `must` clause, then it will have a higher relevancy score, assuming that `term2`, `term3` and `term4` are queries that calculate a relevancy score.

On this basis, the query that you would like to generate expresses that for a document to be considered a match, it must match all of the 4 queries in the `must` clause

```
"must": [
  {
    "term": { "truckOemName": { "value": "HYSTER" }}
  },
  {
    "term": {"truckModelName": { "value": "S40FT" }}
  },
  {
    "term": {"partCategoryCode": { "value": "RECO" }}
  },
  {
    "exists": { "field": "partID" }
  }
],
```

then, for documents matching the `must` clauses, if

1. it has a `serialRangeInclusiveFrom` less than or equal to `"F187V-6785D"` and a `serialRangeInclusiveFrom` greater than or equal to `"F187V-6060D"`

   or
2. `serialRangeInclusiveFrom` and `serialRangeInclusiveTo`

then boost that documents relevancy score. The crucial point is that

> **If a document matches the `must` clauses but does not match any
>   of the `should` clauses, it will still be a match for the query (but
>   have a lower relevancy score).**

If that is the intent, this query can be constructed [using the longer form of the `Bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-query-usage.html)

Comment: I've added the rest of the required boolean logic.  To be clear, truckOemName, truckModelName, partCategoryCode, partId exists AND (matching serialRange OR null serialRange) are always required. Can you add a NEST query that uses the longer form of `Bool` queries without the overloads that matches this?  I'll start messing with rewriting to remove those overloads as well.

Comment: Marking this as the answer for now until I have time to test & write NEST queries without the operator overloads.  This is why it's not working but not code that does work.